# Warning initialization makes pointer form integer without a cast

Tags: c

I am getting the warning initialization makes pointer form integer without a cast when I try to test my code using this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "List.h"
#include "List.c"
int main()
{
    int k;
    // make list
    ListP r = newlist();
    //check if empty
    k = isEmptyList(r);
    if(k=0)
    {
        printf("this list is empty");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("List not empty");
    }
    //display
    displayList(r);
    //insert
    insertItemList(r, "shuan");
    //check if empty
    k = isEmptyList(r);
    if(k=0)
    {
        printf("this list is empty");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("List not empty");
    }
    //display
    displayList(r);
    return 0;   
}
```

The error says it in the line with the newList() call the function for the new list is

```
typedef struct List
{
    struct Node* head;
    int size;   
}List;

typedef struct Node
{
    char *info;
    struct Node* next;
}Node;
typedef struct Node *NodeP;
typedef struct List *ListP;

//makes a list
ListP newList()
{   
    List *p;
    ListP g;
    p = (List*) malloc(sizeof(List));
    if(p == NULL) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed!\n");
        exit(1);
    };
    p->size = 0;
    p->head == NULL;
    g = p;
    return g;
};
```

Does this mean that the function is exiting 1 because malloc isn't allocating memory for the list and is not in the right syntax or is there another problem with the code? Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please indent your code, this is barely readable.

Comment: why do you #include "List.c"?

Comment: I deleted my answer as the question changed after I posted it. You have a few bugs in your code. Frankly I'm not sure how you were able to get it to compile. First, you call `newlist()` instead of `newList()` in `main()`. Second, you perform comparison rather than assignment in `newList()`. Change `p->head == NULL` to `p->head = NULL`. I fixed those issues and was able to compile and run it with no problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you should get also a warning about 'unknown' function. That means that there is a problem with function `newList` and compiler assumes the unknown function returns int, and continues on..

Possible reason: the function is named newList but you use

```
ListP r = newlist();
             ^
```

You should double check if proper **headers** are included and names are correct, and that **the function is declared before** it's used. Search case sensitive (grep is by default case sensitive so something like

```
grep -r "newlist" .  // verify
grep -r "newList" .  // again...
```

will work) in your project root dir for "newlist" & for "newList". You shouldn't also

```
#include "List.c"
```

but only

```
#include "List.h"
```

Then correct also comparison `p->head == NULL;` to assignment `p->head = NULL;`

Comment: The project is broken up into 3 parts i have a header List.h where all the functions used in the project are declared, the List.c where are the functions and the code for them are, and the List_test.c where I test the code.  I was trying to only post the relevant code and just copy paste the whole project. The only warning I am getting when I compile is the  initialization makes pointer form integer without a cast.

Comment: correct the latter "l" (ascii 0x6c) to capital "L" (0x4c)

Comment: Thanks, I'm surprised I didn't catch that copying all of this over.

Comment: you will find yourself many times fighting with something such unfair as this case, this is what preserves the world and technology from growing smoothly